# javax.jms.JMSException: maximum connections (50) reached error while configuring more than 50 resource adapters - MDB

Tags: jms, websphere, message-queue, websphere-8, jboss6.x

We are getting the below exception when we try to configure more than 50 MDB (each MDB to a different MQ). I have tried changing the standalone.xml configuration as below, but still it didnt help. Could someone help us on this ?

standalone.xml

```
<short-running-threads>
    <core-threads count="90"/>
    <queue-length count="90"/>
    <max-threads count="90"/>
    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
</short-running-threads>
<long-running-threads>
    <core-threads count="90"/>
    <queue-length count="90"/>
    <max-threads count="90"/>
    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
</long-running-threads>
```

Stacktrace:

> ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 185)
>   MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.subunit."test.ear"."testAppMDB.jar".component.TESTMDB.START:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.subunit."test.ear"."TestAppMDB.jar".component.TESTMDB.START:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException:
>   MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011
>   An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail.
>   See the linked exception for details of the failure. at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14] at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102] at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_102] at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException:
>   MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011
>   An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail.
>   See the linked exception for details of the failure. at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent.activate(MessageDrivenComponent.java:209)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent.start(MessageDrivenComponent.java:181)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14] ... 6
>   more Caused by:
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException:
>   MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011
>   An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail.
>   See the linked exception for details of the failure. at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:134)
>   at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:105)
>   at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:165)
>   at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.acquireConnection(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:284)
>   at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:233)
>   at
>   com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:393)
>   at org.jboss.jca.core.rar.EndpointImpl.activate(EndpointImpl.java:191)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent.activate(MessageDrivenComponent.java:207)
>   ... 8 more Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: maximum connections (50)
>   reached at com.ibm.mq.connector.in

Answer (score 1):

This exception

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: maximum connections (50) reached at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection
```

is a result of default setting (50) of the `maxConnection` property in the WebSphere MQ Resource adapter. Check this page for more details [Configuring properties for the IBM MQ resource adapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/tmm_wmqra_propconfig.html).

You need to change this property in the resource adapter configuration. I dont know how you configure it in JBoss, but in WebSphere you do it via Resources > JMS > JMS providers > Resource adapter properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the formatting of the stack-trace, but it appears to me that the exception is coming from the WebSphereMQ JCA Resource Adapter which indicates that the problem is with the configuration of the WebSphereMQ server which appears to be limiting the number of possible connections to 50.  Changing thread-pool configurations in the JBoss application server isn't going to resolve the issue.  You need to change the WebSphereMQ server to allow more than 50 connections.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes you are correct in the way thats not the issue with JBoss. Because the same MDB configuration worked in another environment. We are checking issues at Windows environments, lookslike TCP/IP configuration is blocking this in our server. But unable to get a clear picture till now. Will share the details if we able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number number of available connections (defaults to 50):

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq-jmsra.rar" statistics-enabled="true">
                <archive>
                    wmq-jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <config-property name="maxConnections">
                    100
                </config-property>
```